# RealityKit: Surface Deform Modifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, realitykit

Goal: Use one mesh to deform another mesh in RealityKit.

This would be the equivalent of "surface deform modifier" in Blender: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/surface_deform.html

"The Surface Deform modifier allows an arbitrary mesh surface to control the deformation of another, essentially transferring its motion/deformation."

Use case: You have a hair/curve mesh, then you deform on a dog, and you have the dog mesh with the hair.

What I tried: I looked into this API; but seems that the mesh ca only be deformed from an image or shader, and not another geometry https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadermodifierentrypoint/1524108-geometry

Question: How can I deform one mesh using another mesh in RealityKit?